# Reverse Odd-length Words in the given String in Java

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I expect the User to provide a sentence.

And as an output, they will reverse a string with only the odd-length words reversed (*i.e. even-length words should remain intact*).

```
static String secretAgentII(String s) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String[] newStr = s.split(" ");
    String result = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++) {
        if (newStr[i].length() % 2 != 0) {
            sb.append(newStr[i]).reverse();
            result += sb + " ";
        }

        result += newStr[i] + " ";
    }

    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(secretAgentII(s));
}
```

*Input:*

> One two three Four

*Expected Output:*

> enO owT eerhT Four

*The actual Output:*

> enO One owtOne two eerhtenOtwo three Four

How can I fix that?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: So, as I have mentioned in the question itself hope you can understand it?

Comment: You only mentioned the output you had with your existing program, what different output did you expect the program to give?

Answer (score 0):

In your method `secretAgentII` the StringBuffer should have no other values so that it would not be concatenated to other strings.

I placed `sb.replace(0, newStr[i].length(), newStr[i]).reverse();` inside the for loop so that it would replace the existing string in every use.

I also placed an else before the line `result += newStr[i] + " ";` for the original string doesn't need to be concatenated when it is reversed.

```
static String secretAgentII(String s) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String[] newStr = s.split(" ");
    String result = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++) {
        if (newStr[i].length() % 2 != 0) {
            sb.replace(0, newStr[i].length(), newStr[i]).reverse();
            result += sb + " ";
        } else
            result += newStr[i] + " ";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Input: `One Two Three Four`

Output: `enO owT eerhT Four`

note: you are using too many spaces, try researching Java conventions on writing code.

Comment: Actually the expected result is enO owT eerhT Four

Comment: I'll edit my answer shortly

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and wrote a method for what I think you are asking for.

```java
    public static String secretAgentII(String input){
        StringBuilder returnValue = new StringBuilder();
        input = input.replaceAll(" +", " ");
        String[] tempArray = input.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
            String currentString = tempArray[i];
            if (currentString.length() % 2 == 1) {
                char[] tempArrayOfStringChars = currentString.toCharArray();
                for (int j = tempArrayOfStringChars.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    returnValue.append(tempArrayOfStringChars[j]);
                }
            } else {
                returnValue.append(currentString);
            }
            if (i != tempArray.length - 1) { //This prevents a leading space at the end of your string
                returnValue.append(' ');
            }
        }
        return returnValue.toString();
    }
```

From what I could tell, you only want the words of odd length to be reversed.

My sample input and output was as follows.

```
Input: One two three four five six seven eight nine ten
Output: enO owt eerht four five xis neves thgie nine net
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you add to `result` the whole `sb`, instead of just the current reverse word. Meaning you need to "reset" (create a `new`) `StringBurrer` for each iteration.

You're also missing the `else` where you want to preserve the correct word's order

```
for (int i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++) {
    if (newStr[i].length() % 2 == 1) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(newStr[i]);
        result += sb.reverse() + " ";
    }
    else {
        result += newStr[i] + " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) + [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/StringJoiner.html)

Never use plain string concatenation the loop because in Java `String`s are immutable. That means every `s1 + s2` produces new intermediate string, which don't need (since only the end result would be used). Concatenation in the loop effects performance and increase memory allocation.

Therefore, it's highly advisable to use `StringBuilder`, or other built-in mechanisms like static method `String.join()`, `StringJoiner` or Collector `joining()` when you need to combine multiple strings together.

To avoid bother about adding a white space after each word ourself, we can make use of the `StringJoiner`. Through its parameterized constructor we can provide the required delimiter `" "`.

That's how it might be implemented:

```
public static String reverseOdd1(String str) {
    StringJoiner result = new StringJoiner(" ");
    String[] words = str.split(" ");
    
    for (String word : words) {
        if (word.length() % 2 != 0) result.add(new StringBuilder(word).reverse());
        else result.add(word);
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

***Note** that it's not advisable to use* `StringBuffer` *in single-threaded environment because its methods are synchronized to make it tread-safe (and synchronization doesn't come for free), and instead use it sibling* `StringBuilder` *which has the same methods.*

Here's a couple of more **advanced** solutions.

## Stream IPA - [`Collectors.joining()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining(java.lang.CharSequence))

You can generate a Stream of words, revers odd-length words using `map()` operation, and generate the resulting string using Collector `joining()`.

```
public static String reverseOdd2(String str) {
    
    return Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))
        .map(s -> s.length() % 2 == 0 ? s : new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString())
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

## Regex - [`Matcher.replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function))

Another option is to use regular expressions.

To capture a separate word we can use the following pattern:

```
public static final Pattern WORD = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\w+)\\b");
```

Where `\\b` is a so-called *boundary matcher* denoting a word boundary (*for more information, refer to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)*).

We can create a `Matcher` instance using this patter and the given string and make use of the Java 9 method `Matcher.replaceAll()` to generate the resulting string.

```
public static String reverseOdd3(String str) {
    
    return WORD.matcher(str).replaceAll(matchResult -> {
        String group = matchResult.group(1);
        return group.length() % 2 == 0 ? group : new StringBuilder(group).reverse().toString();
    });
}
```

## Usage Example

`main`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(reverseOdd1("One Two Three Four"));
    System.out.println(reverseOdd2("One Two Three Four"));
    System.out.println(reverseOdd3("One Two Three Four"));
}
```

*Output:*

```
enO owT eerhT Four
enO owT eerhT Four
enO owT eerhT Four
```